# Gulp JS compression and git conflict resolution

Tags: javascript, git, gulp, merge-conflict-resolution

I want to have a Gulp task that will watch JS files in my source directory for changes and automatically uglify and update the corresponding compressed file in my dist/build directory.

If a git conflict occurs in the source, it will occur in the compressed version as well.  I'm concerned that I'll run into this scenario:

- Start conflict resolution
- Resolve conflict in source and save
- Gulp sees the change, compresses, and updates the compressed version
- Git conflict resolution proceeds to the conflicted compressed file
- Resolve conflict in the compressed one and save; this overwrites the wonderful work Gulp just did

As a side note, since the compressed version is a single line of code, the conflict resolution there may be... interesting.

Is there a way to either:

- Have Gulp wait until git conflict resolution is done, then do the compression
- During git conflict resolution, knowing that Gulp will handle making the compressed file be what it should be after the resolved source file is saved to disk, avoid doing anything at all with the compressed file and tell git it's good to go (mark the conflict on the file as resolved without modifying it)

From what I know of both tools, I kind of suspect the right way to go is the latter of the two.

Comment: Are you versioning your compiled files (meaning, app.min.js)? If so, why?

Comment: Yes.  Currently I'm exploring the use of Gulp in our team's workflow.  If I can demonstrate its value, our team may adopt it.  Until then I can't remove the compressed versions from the repo :)